# How to generate syntactically correct JSON example for List<String> with Swagger annotation

Tags: java, spring-boot, swagger, springfox

I am using `springfox-boot-starter`. Is there a way of handling the `example` value properly for a field which is `List<String>`?

Neither `@ApiModelProperty` nor `@Schema` generates the correct result.

```java
import io.swagger.annotations.ApiModelProperty;
import io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.media.Schema;

public class MyRequest {
    @ApiModelProperty(dataType = "List", example = "[\"value1-1\", \"value1-2\"]")
    private List<String> list1;

    @Schema(type = "array", example = "[\"value2-1\",\"value2-2\"]")
    private List<String> list2;

    @Schema(example = "[\"value3-1\",\"value3-2\"]")
    private List<String> list3;
}
```

The example JSON request generated on `http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui/index.html` is like this:

```js
{
  "list1": "[\"value1-1\", \"value1-2\"]",
  "list2": "[\"value2-1\", \"value2-2\"]",
  "list3": "[\"value3-1\", \"value3-2\"]"
}
```

instead of what I would expect

```js
{
  "list1": ["value1-1", "value1-2"],
  "list2": ["value2-1", "value2-2"],
  "list3": ["value3-1", "value3-2"]
}
```

It seems like there is a bug in Springfox, see [issue #3863](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/issues/3863) and [issue #1855](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/issues/1855).